# GAE datastore -- proper ways to implement search/data retrieval in response to a user request?

Tags: google-app-engine, search

I am writing a web app and I am trying to improve the performance of search/displaying results. I am relatively new to programming this sort of thing, so I apologize in advance if these are simple questions/concepts.

Right now I have a database of ~20,000 sites, each with properties, and I have a search form that (for now) just asks the database to pull all sites within a set distance (for this example, say 50km). I have put the data into an index and use the Search API to find sites.

I am noticing that the database search takes ~2-3 seconds to:
1) Search the index
2) Get a list of key names (this is stored in the search index)
3) Using key names, pull from datastore (in a loop) and extract data properties to be displayed to the user
4) Transmit data to the user via jinja template variables

This is also only getting 20 results (the default maximum for a Search API query.. I haven't implemented cursors here yet, although I will have to).

For whatever reason, it feels quite slow.. I am wondering what websites do to make the process seem faster. Do they implement some kind of "asynchronous" search, where a page loads while in the background the search/data pulls are processed, and then subsequently shown to the user...?

Are there "standard" ways of performing searches here where the processing/loading feels seamless to the user?

Thanks.

**edit**

Would doing something like just passing a "query ID" via the page work, and then using AJAX to get data from the datastore via JSON work? Like... can app engine redirect the user to the final page, pass in only a "query ID", and then search in the meantime, and then once the data is ready, pass the information the user via JSON?

Comment: The only part that sounds suspicious is "pull from datastore (in a loop)". You should be using `ndb.get_multi` (assuming you're using ndb and python).

Comment: I'm just using db.. is there a way to have similar functionality with db? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you just have to create `Key` objects and pass them into `Model.get`. Something like `MyModel.get([Key.from_path('MyModel', key_name) for key_name in key_names])`.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it and it sped up retrieval to < 1 second.

Comment: Is there any difference that you know of between what you wrote and just doing:
`MyModel.get_by_key_name(key_names)`? Thanks

Comment: Nope, I just forgot about that method. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are getting entities from the datastore in parallel. Since you already have the key names, you just have to pass your list of keys to the appropriate method.

For [db](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_key_name):

```
MyModel.get_by_key_name(key_names)
```

For [ndb](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions):

```
ndb.get_multi([ndb.Key.from_path('MyModel', key_name) for key_name in key_names])
```

If you needed to do datastore queries, you could enable parallel fetches with the `query.run` (db) and `query.fetch_async` (ndb) methods.